# How do I add a drop down list in react js within a table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, dropdown

`var ListItem = React.createClass({ displayName: "ListItem",
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {fruit: this.props.value.product.fruit, meat: this.props.value.product.meat, vegetable: this.props.value.product.vegetable, total: 0 };
  },



render: function () {
    return (
      React.createElement("tr", null, 
      React.createElement("td", null, React.createElement("input", { type: "text", name: "fruit", value: this.state.fruit, onChange: this.handleChange, placeholder: "fruit" })), 
      React.createElement("td", null, React.createElement("input", { type: "number", name: "meat", value: this.state.meat, onChange: this.handleChange, placeholder: "..." })), 
      React.createElement("td", null, React.createElement("input", { type: "number", name: "vegetable", value: this.state.vegetable, onChange: this.handleChange, placeholder: "..." })), 
      React.createElement("td", { className: "total" }, this.state.total)));
  },`

Now I want to change Fruit, Meat and Vegetable to "form" instead of "input" with drop down options so when I click on Fruit I will have drop down options of "apple, banana, strawberry". Meat options will be "pork, beef, lamb" etc...

I've try using

```
return React.createElement("select", {},
  React.createElement("option", {value: "A"}, "Option A"),
  React.createElement("option", {value: "B"}, "Option B"),
  React.createElement("option", {value: "C"}, "Option C")
);
```

but it doesn't work :(

Comment: https://en.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: @pepinillo6969 this won't work since I need the options "apple, banana, strawberry" to store a value. each option is storing a value i.e. apple = 1, banana = 2